# mysql cron job - Email only when restarted

Tags: mysql, cron, email

I've got the following cron job and it runs every 5 minutes (it actually works)

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
if [[ "$(/usr/sbin/service mysql status)" != *start/running* ]]
then
    echo "MySQL restarted" | mail -a FROM:*@*  -s "[Marketing Server] Database Service" *@*
    sudo service mysql start
fi
```

When running mysql status (running)

`mysql.service - LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon
 Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mysql)
 Active: active (exited) since Wed 2015-12-09 15:01:40 GMT; 21h ago
 Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
 Process: 30829 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/mysql stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Process: 30910 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mysql start (code=exited,status=0/SUCCESS)`

`Dec 10 12:10:02 MarketingServer systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start and stop the ....
Dec 10 12:15:02 MarketingServer systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start and stop the ....
Dec 10 12:20:02 MarketingServer systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start and stop the ....
Dec 10 12:25:01 MarketingServer systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start and stop the ....
Dec 10 12:30:02 MarketingServer systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start and stop the ....
Dec 10 12:35:01 MarketingServer systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start and stop the ....
Dec 10 12:40:01 MarketingServer systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start and stop the ....
Dec 10 12:45:02 MarketingServer systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start and stop the ....
Dec 10 12:50:02 MarketingServer systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start and stop the ....
Dec 10 12:55:01 MarketingServer systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start and stop the ....
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.`

when running mysql status (stopped)

`david@MarketingServer:~$ sudo service mysql stop
^[[Adavid@MarketingServer:~$ sudo service mysql status
● mysql.service - LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mysql)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Thu 2015-12-10 13:03:26 GMT; 1s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 5024 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/mysql stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 30910 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mysql start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)`

`Dec 10 12:35:01 MarketingServer systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start and stop the ....
Dec 10 12:40:01 MarketingServer systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start and stop the ....
Dec 10 12:45:02 MarketingServer systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start and stop the ....
Dec 10 12:50:02 MarketingServer systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start and stop the ....
Dec 10 12:55:01 MarketingServer systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start and stop the ....
Dec 10 13:00:02 MarketingServer systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start and stop the ....
Dec 10 13:03:24 MarketingServer systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: Start and stop the....
Dec 10 13:03:24 MarketingServer mysql[5024]: * Stopping MySQL database serve...d
Dec 10 13:03:26 MarketingServer mysql[5024]: ...done.
Dec 10 13:03:26 MarketingServer systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Start and stop the ....
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.`

The only issue I have is it sends a email stating the service has been restarted every time, even when it hasn't. I want it to only send when the service actually has restarted from stopped.

Can anyone explain which part i've got wrong

Comment: Are you certain that the service doesn't get restarted every time the mail is sent? Restarting doesn't imply that it was stopped before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issue in your if statement.
The`!` at the beginning of condition test means that you're looking for whether the expression `"$(/usr/sbin/service mysql status)"` is false, which is not what you want to achieve. You want to check that the outcome of service status command is not a string that contains 'start/waiting'. `!=` is the best way to say not equal to.

Also, the `=~` is expecting a regular expression, where you're just supplying a part of the string that you expect to see. As the double bracket syntax of if statements supports shell globbing, you can search for the 'start/waiting' with `*start/waiting*`.

If you change the line:

```
if [[ ! "$(/usr/sbin/service mysql status)" =~ "start/running" ]]
```

To:

```
if [[ "$(/usr/sbin/service mysql status)" != *start/running* ]]
```

Your script should work properly, otherwise, I think you're restarting the service, and emailing, every time the script runs.

EDIT:

The following is not an ideal solution, I'm just posting it to try to help with the current situation you're facing.

To try to cope with output from `systemd-sysv-generator` you could try replacing the first line of the `if` statement with:

```
if [[ "$(/usr/sbin/service mysql status)" = *inactive* ]]
```

Comment: Good points, but the way I read the question is that the mail gets sent even though the service has not been restarted.

Comment: @Jos I could be mistaken, but I think that if the mail is being sent, the `sudo service mysql start` command will happen too. Both commands in the 'then' part of the if statement will be executed, or neither, and I don't see any checking of whether the service is actually started or not. It's only testing whether the service has stopped.

Comment: Thanks Arronical i will make this change and see what happens.

Jos It most certainly was running and sending each time

I'm hoping now it will only do it when the service does restart.

Comment: @Arronical will it matter that i get the following output when running service mysql status

`@MarketingServer:~$ service mysql status
● mysql.service - LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mysql)
   Active: active (exited) since Thu 2015-12-03 17:04:22 GMT; 5 days ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)

Dec 09 13:55:02 MarketingServer systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start and stop the ....
Dec 09 14:00:01 MarketingServer systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start and stop the ....`

Comment: Ah, your system runs under `systemd` whereas your script expects an `upstart` job. The same command (`service mysql status`) works but produces different output, as you have noticed. You should modify the "if" command to include the significant bits from your output.

Comment: I have no idea how to change the script to that, i merly based this script on another cron job i saw. I've never had to use cron to monitor mysql as it never normally fails...

Comment: You can change the `*start/running*` part to include some of the output from the service status command that you only see when the service is running, which will probably work on this server, while it's on this version of Ubuntu, because `systemd` and `upstart` kind of run in tandem. **But** it's likely to fail if you try to use it on another server, or upgrade your OS. What's the output of `service mysql status` when it's not working?

Comment: Under systemd, if a service is not running, the command `service [name] status` will produce several lines, one of them containing `active (running)`. Otherwise, it will be `inactive (dead)`. Perhaps you can `grep` for that.

Comment: @Arronical 
this is the output when the service is not running `MarketingServer:~$ service mysql status
● mysql.service - LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mysql)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Wed 2015-12-09 15:01:32 GMT; 2s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 30829 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/mysql stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Dec 09 14:35:24 MarketingServer systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start and stop the ....`

Comment: @Arronical Any chance you can help further?

Comment: I've been struggling to test for 'inactive (dead)', I can't really test as I don't have an installation that gives the same output. I'll do an edit with a suggestion, can you confirm that the word 'inactive' never appears in the output from the service command when the database is still running?

Comment: @Arronical Added the full output to the original question

Comment: @Arronical you're modification worked! it now only starts if it is stopped as i wanted.

Many thanks!